# system monitoring tools

Tags: solaris, top, system-information

What command line utilities come standard with sunos to do system monitoring?

I've been able to find `prstat`, but I would like something that will tell me memory usage and IOWAIT as well.

It looks like this particular machine uses sunos 5.8

Comment: vmstat, iostat, sar, ... prstat does tell you about memory usage. Also, time for an update, 5.8 is getting really old.

Comment: You don't need to include "solaris" in your title, that's what tags are for

Comment: What you have is actually Solaris 8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are plenty of monitoring CLI commands with Solaris. They are easy to find as almost all share the stat suffix:

- vmstat
- mpstat
- iostat
- netstat
- lockstat
- nfsstat
- prstat
- busstat
- cpustat
- kstat
- sar
- swap

`kstat` (or the equivalent `netstat -k`) provides all of the kernel statistics in raw form.

About the IOWAIT statistic, note that the fact it was often poorly understood, wrongly interpreted and meaningless with fast and/or multi core / multi threaded CPUs, it is no more reported by `vmstat` on modern (10+) Solaris releases.

Comment: The list is pretty cool, i would like to add some, rpcinfo - nfs statistcs/troubleshooting, ypwhich - NIS related things